# How to store old streaming data in Databricks Spark?

Tags: scala, databricks

I am new to Spark Streaming and Azure Databricks. I read many articles on how spark works and process data etc. But what about old data? If spark works on interactive data then my 2 weeks older or 2 months older data can Spark hold? or suppose I have to move data after transformation where should I move and clear the spark memory? will it store in SSD only?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Databricks supports several data stores (as a source and as a target for data at rest). Good practice for Big Data is mounting an Azure Data Lake Store. If you have a streaming data source (like Kafka or EventHubs) you can use it as a sink and of cause reuse it for further analytics.

See https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/index.html for supported data sources.